# Can virent/viret mean "green" in an adjectival sense?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

In the Latin translation.of Green Eggs and Ham, they repeat the phrase "Virent Ova! Viret Perna!"

From the context I believe this is means "Green Eggs! Green Ham!", but I thought virent was a verb that meant "they are green," as in, "they are full of life and vitality." I'm not sure that fits? "The eggs are green with life and vitality! The ham is verdant with energy!" ??

What's the best way, in context, to translate this line into English?

Comment: Just an additional note: the "full of life and vitality" is a metaphorical understanding based on the ideas that younger plants are greener than aged plants. It's not the primary meaning.

Comment: Primary meaning would be "is green" then?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Indeed, *vireō* is a verb meaning "to be green", so this line says "the eggs are green, the ham is green".

It was generally used in the sense of a green plant (i.e. a lively, leafy one), but it could also describe other green things: Martial (VI.42.11) says *illic Taygeti virent metalla*, "the quarries of Taygetus shine green there", referring to the color of the porphyry stone extracted from Mount Taygetus.

Answer (score 1):

The well-known Latin word for “green” is viridis. It is difficult to understand why the translator has not rendered “green eggs” as ova viridia, but replaced this by words meaning “the eggs are green”. Baffling.

Comment: I suspect metrical reasons.